# Problema con Declaracion ORDER BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente inquietud:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar este query

```
SELECT * FROM la_tabla ORDER BY padre
```

la fila 4 deberia ubicarse debajo de la fila 1, sin embargo estoy obteniendo este resultado, Cual es el error aqui?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si el contenido de la columna de orden incluye valores nulos estos son omitidos por el `ORDER BY`, sencillamente porque un `NULL` no es un valor.

Comment: ¿Cual es tu base de datos, MySQL o PostgreSQL? Tienes ambas etiquetas. ¿Puedes explicar un poco más en cuanto a cual es la lógica detrás del orden que esperas obtener?  Es fácil decir que quieres un registro debajo de otra, pero hay que entender la lógica detrás de lo que quieres.

Comment: hola amigo @sstan trabajo con postgresql, recuerdo que me ayudaste con un post similar, la logica es que cada registro nuevo "heredara" el id padre de arriba, por tanto cuando se haga el select all, deberia posicionarse debajo de su padre

Comment: Estoy confundido por la respuesta que aceptastes, porque no corresponde a tu descripción de querer ordenar por la relación padre-hijo, de hecho el SQL ni siquiera es válido.

Comment: hola @sstan Como puedes observar en mi tabla en la columna padre tengo filas vacias, cuando estan asi, la declaracion order by no funciona como deberia, en cambio cuando estan llenas, si realiza el trabajo requerido, lo acabo de probar y funciona

Comment: ¿Entonces tu intención era de agrupar todos los padres primero, y luego todos los hijos, o querías que cada hijo esté debajo de su padre? Porque la solución aceptada usa la primera opción que no sonaba a lo que querías.  Tal vez, como ya se te comentó, no tienes suficientes datos para comprobar que funciona de verdad. ¿Qué pasaría si tuvieras otra hijo, pero con un padre `ID 2` por ejemplo. ¿Qué sucedería entonces?

Comment: cada hijo debajo de su padre, si crean otros datos, el query continuaria funcionando por que siempre tomara el de arriba y se colocara "debajo"

Comment: Ese query definitivamente no pone los hijos debajo de sus respectivos padres. Si estás bajo la impresión que sí, entonces o no estás usando la misma consulta, o no tienes suficientes datos de prueba para darte cuenta que no funciona así.

Comment: Si te gusta leer he aquí la solución: https://coderwall.com/p/whf3-a/hierarchical-data-in-postgres. Disculpa no puedo hacer una respuesta ahora, no tengo suficiente tiempo.

Comment: Debes considerar cambiar el título de la pregunta, porque definitivamente es un problema de agrupación - ordenación jerárquico y eso desde mi punto de vista es muy interesante. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que pasa es que los valores nulos no pueden ser sorteados por el ORDER BY.

Te sugiero que intentes darle un valor para cuando estén nulos, así:

```
SELECT * FROM la_tabla ORDER BY padre WHEN padre is null THEN "" ELSE padre END, padre
```

El "WHEN" evaluará que si es nulo pone un string "vacío" que sí puede sorteado.

Comment: Bingo. Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Este código funciona para este caso, pero ¿qué pasa si tiene más de un contenido en la columna padre?  Si el OP quiere obtener una ordenación parent child.

Comment: @Blasito podrías explicarme lo de "más de un contenido", gracias.

Comment: sería más registros con valores en la columna padre.

Comment: @Blasito sencillo, para eso es la sentencia ELSE, si el valor no está nulo muestra el valor en sí (ELSE padre). Así, ordenará todos los valores independientemente del valor.

Comment: Así es, pero según el contenido de la pregunta el OP está queriendo obtener una ordenación de acuerdo al padre, es decir si el `idtable` es igual a `1` entonces todos las filas que tengan como padre al uno que se muestre por debajo del registro y así también si el `idtable` es `2` que se muestren todos los registros que tengan el valor `2` en la columna padre debajo del registro 2.

Comment: @Blasito Específicamente para la ordenación por padre sería colocar en el ORDER BY la variable "padre" antes de la evaluación:

`ORDER BY padre, padre WHEN padre is null THEN "" ELSE padre END`

Answer (score 1):

Comentario de OP:

> la logica es que cada registro nuevo "heredara" el id padre de arriba, por tanto cuando se haga el select all, deberia posicionarse debajo de su padre.

La solución más sencilla a este problema depende de cuántos niveles de padre-hijo permites.  Si solo puede haber un nivel, o sea que nunca pueden haber "abuelos", entonces se puede hacer el orden de esta manera:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM la_tabla 
 ORDER BY case when padre is null then id else padre end, -- agrupa hijos con padres
          padre is not null,                              -- hijos después de padres
          id                                              -- hijos en orden de ID
```

... dónde con la expresión `CASE` los hijos son ordenados usando el `ID` del padre para que queden agrupados juntos.

Pero si es posible tener varios niveles de padres-hijos, entonces es necesario usar una consulta recursiva. Este sería un ejemplo (inspirado de [esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63161/72418)):

```
with recursive cte as (
  select id, contenido, padre, array[id] as path
    from la_tabla
   where padre is null
   union all
  select t.id, t.contenido, t.padre, c.path || t.id as path
    from cte c
    join la_tabla t
      on t.padre = c.id
)
select id, contenido, padre
 from cte
 order by path
```

Comment: Gran aporte @sstan Me gustaria aprender sobre consultas recursivas, tienes alguna guia o post?

Comment: Aparte de [la documentación oficial al respecto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html), no, no tengo algo particular al respecto. Puedes buscar en Google por `postgresql recursive queries` o algo así si quieres encontrar más información.

Comment: Ok gracias @sstan estuve practicando tu query y no me traia ningun dato (pero el query no esta malo), por eso queria investigar un poco mas

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que te refieres a ordenar de mayor a menor, siendo el 1 el "mayor" por tener uno a diferencia de los demás que están nulos. Podrías tratar de usar **DESC**

Así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM la_tabla 
ORDER BY padre DESC
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: hola matias, como especifique en el post, necesito es esto. la fila 4 deberia ubicarse debajo de la fila 1

Comment: Por qué la fila 4 debería estar bajo la fila 1 ? Es "Padre" la columna por la que deseas ordenar? Lo digo ya que al tener valores nulos no los mostraría.

Comment: hola matias, crisman contesto la pregunta